# Targeting CSS on div range

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element I populate with $.ajax now I want to fade all the custom loaded elements, the element is already pre-populated with 20 elements when the page loads, I don't want to target those 20. Essentially, how can I target the latter 17 divs assuming I have 37 divs total? Currently I use:

```
while ($(".info #future>center>div").length>20) {
  $(".info #future>center>div:last-child").remove();
}
```

to remove them, but now I also want a fading effect to be applied prior, assigning anything to their class is not an option since that property is already taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `slice() [Slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method of jquery.  Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .slice() method constructs a new jQuery object containing a subset of the elements specified by the start and, optionally, end argument. The supplied start index identifies the position of one of the elements in the set; if end is omitted, all elements after this one will be included in the result.

```
 $('.info #future>center>div').slice(20).remove(); //Where start and end your  index to filter.  I omitted end parameter. if you want you can put it. .slice(20,37)
```

if you want fading effect

```
$('.info #future>center>div').slice(20).fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Comment: How can I not specify the end?

Comment: @user2177393 i dint specified. it will remove all divs starting from 21 to how many divs are there. if you want end. call like this slice(20,37)

Comment: Same problem as I've said in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

take look on jQuery [:gt() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/).

it used to select all elements at an index greater than index provided to it so you can call it with `index = 20`

```
$(".info #future>center>div:gt(20)").remove();
```

Comment: It seems to do it if I refer to every populated element by ID but if I refer to all of them by class (e.g. `$(".info .queue>center>div:gt(19)").animate({opacity:0}, 1500, function())` it seems that on the first .queue everything is done correctly but on the rest all of the divs fade.